# Azure Application Service Environment Internal and External

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, paas

Can an Azure Application Service Environment be configured to host apps that are externally as well as internally accessible?

Or would I have to create an ILB ASE for just the internal only apps, and use an external ASE (or maybe just regular app plans) for all externally accessible apps?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution depends on how much isolation is needed for the internal apps.

One option would be to configure an "external ASE" with a Firewall device, this way you could allow specific apps to be accessed from outside and others to be internal only based.

IF you need complete isolation then having an internal and external ASE would be the way to go.